# django signal default disptch uid value

Tags: python, django, django-signals

i know that in order to prevent duplicate signals, there is a need to add dispatch_uid ([from django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals))

but i noticed that sometimes when i connecting more than two receivers to the same signal (without uid), only one of them is being called.

when i tried to add dispatch uid to one of them, both are called.

what is the reason?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the send method source code:

```
def send(self, sender, **named):
    """
    Send signal from sender to all connected receivers.
    If any receiver raises an error, the error propagates back through send,
    terminating the dispatch loop, so it is quite possible to not have all
    receivers called if a raises an error.
    Arguments:

        sender
            The sender of the signal Either a specific object or None.

        named
            Named arguments which will be passed to receivers.
    Returns a list of tuple pairs [(receiver, response), ... ].
    """
    responses = []
    if not self.receivers:
        return responses

    for receiver in self._live_receivers(_make_id(sender)):
        response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
        responses.append((receiver, response))
    return responses
```

you will notice that the signal should be sent to all receivers regarding whether you have specified the dispatch_uid or not, so I'm guessing that you either connected one of the receivers improperly, or one of them raised an error during execution.